# Programmatically adding new tests via ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a set of input cases stored in a file.

I would like each case to be a specific scalatest "test", i.e., reported in the console as an individual test and failed individually.

Unfortunately, experimentation and Google suggest that this capability might not be present?

E.g., this seems to be the common case (eliding for simplicity)

```
class MyTestingGoop extends FunSuite {
   val input : Seq[SpecificTestCase] = ...
   test("input data test") {
      forAll(input) { case => ... } 
   }
   //...
}
```

Ideally, each `case` presents as a separate test. How can this be done with ScalaTest?

Comment: I would rather add tags(say `PerfTests`) to marke tests, and run tests with that particular tags. Eg. `mvn -DtagsToInclude=PerfTest test`

Comment: @prayagupd : That doesn't address the specific question of having programmatic tests generated and run.

Comment: Oh oh are saying your input is dynamic, could be 10 different inputs and you wanna have 10 tests one for each input? Thats what you mean by programmatic?, if yes thats doeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class MyTestingGoop extends FunSuite {
  val input : Seq[SpecificTestCase] = ...

  forAll(input) {
    test("testing input" + input) {
       // do something with the test
    }
  }
}
```

The only limit is that input has a unique toString.

Basically calling test in Funsuite registers the test and later runs it so as long as your test creation is done as part of the class construction and each test has a unique string, you should be fine.

Comment: Do you know how this technique could be used if "input" is defined by the run method? In my use case at the time of test registration the variable is just an empty list so the tests do not run